# Concantenate before and after entire string in Python

Tags: python, concatenation, string-formatting, slack

I have some table data that I am retrieving from a REST API, I'm then storing this and want to upload it to slack. To upload it to slack I need to enclose the entire object with " `` " . I'm not sure how to do that in Python. The way I'm doing it is -

````
response = '```' + result.astype(str)

``       ``  name               request_id              Slam                       Won
``0   ``nadal.rafael@gmaisd``      ``47``             ``French``               ``12``
4   ``federer.rgoer@gmail ``       `` 57 ``              ``Wimbledon``               ``8 ``
````

I would like the output to be like this , So the entire object is enclosed -

```
``         name               request_id              Slam                       Won
0   nadal.rafael@gmaisd         47               French                          12
4   federer.rgoer@gmail         57                 Wimbledon                     8 ``
```

Answer (score 2):

`astype` is for converting columns, to convert the whole object to a string use `str` or `repr`:

````
'```' + str(result) + '```'
````

Or an f-string in Python 3.6+:

````
f'```{result}```'
````

Comment: Thank you so much, it works! Also hope you're safe and sound at home! :)